# Dealing with the 79 character limit when writing python type annotations

Tags: python, pep8, typing

In writing a script, I ended up with a function signature like the following

`def do_multiprocess_action(some_argument: str, communication_pipe: typing.Optional[multiprocessing.connection.Connection]) -> subprocess.Popen:`

In an attempt to comply with PEP8, I split the definition up like the below

```
def do_multiprocess_action(some_argument: str,
                           communication_pipe: typing.Optional[multiprocessing.connection.Connection]
                           ) -> subprocess.Popen:
```

but with the type anotation, the line is far too long. What's the idiomatic way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the annotation first, then write your function:

```
MultiprocessingConnection = typing.Optional[
    multiprocessing.connection.Connection]

def do_multiprocess_action(some_argument: str, 
    communication_pipe: MultiprocessingConnection) -> subprocess.Popen:
```

Comment: This seems like it could get out of hand very quickly, given a lot of types, but it does seem like an option, nonetheless...